# Referencing a CSS class with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
<body>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#someClass {
    color:red;
}
</style>

</head>

<div id="someClass"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert(document.getElementById("someClass").style.color);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from my code I'm trying to figure out if I can reference a style attribute for a class that's defined in CSS, as opposed to directly in the tag's style attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) - small usage example here.

```js
   alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('someClass')).color);
```

```css
#someClass {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="someClass"></div>
```